# Long always returns -1

Tags: android

I check a webside if new items have been posted and if yes a string value "new" is added to these items.

Now the long value "date" always stays on -1, as a result the string value "new" is added after every item, also for items added for example yesterday.
"new" should not be shown for values older then today, please help.

Thank you.

```
public class TopicView extends LinearLayout implements LoadTopicImageCallback {

private LoadTopicImageTask topicImageTask = null;
private boolean newItem = false;
private long date = -1;

public TopicView(final Context context, final Topic topic) {
    super(context);
    init(topic);
}

public TopicView(final Context context, final Topic topic, final String suffix) {
    super(context);
    init(topic);

    final long latest = new Settings(context).getLatest(suffix);
    try {
        final Date d = Util.parseDate(topic.getTime());
        date = d.getTime();
    } catch (final ParseException e) {
    }
    //String new gets added//
    if (latest == -1 || date > latest) {
        findViewById(R.id.topic_view_new).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        newItem = true;
    }
}

public boolean isNewItem() {
    return newItem;
}

public long getDate() {
    return date;
}
```

EDIT:

```
public static String formatDate(final long dt) {
    return formatDate(new Date(dt));
}

public static String formatDate(final Date date) {
    final DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.SHORT);
    return df.format(date);
}

public static final Date parseDate(final String date) throws ParseException {
    final String pattern = "EEE MMM dd, yyyy h:mm a";
    return parseDate(date, pattern);
}

public static final Date parseDate(final String date, final String pattern)
        throws ParseException {
    final SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, Locale.US);
    return format.parse(date);
}
```

Comment: Try debugging your code on line `date=d.getTime();`

Comment: it could be possible it gets into parseException block

Comment: Also, the first constructor does not initialize `date` then it remains `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're sure that you're calling the second constructor, you never initialise the `date` here:

```
public TopicView(final Context context, final Topic topic) {
    super(context);
    init(topic);
    // add some initialisation for "date" here
}
```

And even if you are, it would've been helpful to see that small part of code too.

As an aside, can I point out that it's fine to consume exceptions, but even a shred of debug output can help you in the long run. Maybe change

```
try {
    final Date d = Util.parseDate(topic.getTime());
    date = d.getTime();
} catch (final ParseException e) {
}
```

to:

```
try {
    final Date d = Util.parseDate(topic.getTime());
    date = d.getTime();
} catch (final ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); // Or some log that your define yourself.
}
```

Comment: indeed forgot to add the printStackTrace, here is the exception: 12-22 13:56:35.065: E/ParseException:(20865): java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "19 minutes ago" (at offset 0)
I also edited my code with the Date functions, any clue?

Comment: Here's your error: "Unparseable date: "19 minutes ago"" - isn't a date. You'll have to calculate the difference from the last device update time to the last updated item from your website/server and then decide if you need to refresh.

Comment: thx but i`m really stuck, can you point the direction through any adjustmentcode pls?
How to convert back and calculate the difference?